# Apache Pig -- how to load a file having fields enclosed within double quotes and separated by comma

Tags: apache-pig

Lets assume a file "test1" having two fields "a" & "b".

sample value:

"Hi, how are you", "1"

"It's too hot","2"

Note first record is having 2 comma, and is distinguished as 2 column values only using double quotes.
Second record is having one comma any ways.

How to write a pig scripts which will load the file having values within double quotes. So basically want to tell Pig interpreter that the field values is enclosed within double quotes.

Similar thing can be achieved in Hive as given below:

*create table test1(

    a string
   ,b string
       );
     row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'   with serdeproperties( 
     "separatorChar" = "\,", 
     "quoteChar" = "\"")

     stored as textfile;*

Answer (score 1):

```
A = LOAD '/path/to/file/' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '","'));

C = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE($0,'"',''), REPLACE($1,'"','');

STORE C INTO '/path/to/output/';
```

I am sorry I could not test this, but I had this issue before. Hope it helps and would love to see if there are other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSVExcelStorage loader from Pig. The double quotes in data are handled by this loader. You have to register Piggy-bank jar for using this loader.

`Register ${jar_location}/piggybank-0.15.0.jar;`

`load_data = load '${data_location}' using 
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',');`

Hope this helps.